# How to handle rendering utf-8 characters with size >= 2B properly?

Tags: c++, text, utf-8, freetype, freetype2

I want to render characters that have utf-8 size >= 2 bytes. I have already got everything done. There is one problem, though. When a character is drawn, there is also a something following it [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LcRHc.png)

To get a glyph data I use freetype. This is the very minimal implementation, the actual code contains kerning, SDF, etc.

What I think needs explantaion is a atlas. Method "TextureAtlas::PackTexture(data, w, h)" packs a texture data and returns position, origin - top left corner - within the atlas w and h range. So a first char has a origin = [0, 0] and the next char with width lets say `50` will have the origin at [50, 0]. Shortly saying.

```cpp
    enum
    {
        DPI = 72,
        HIGHRES = 64
    };

    struct Glyph
    {
        uint32 codepoint = -1;
        uint32 width = 0; 
        uint32 height = 0;

        Vector2<int> bearing = 0;
        Vector2<float> advance = 0.0f;
        float s0, t0, s1, t1;
    };

    class TextureFont
    {
    public:
        TextureFont() = default;

        bool Initialize();
        void LoadFromFile(const std::string& filePath, float fontSize);

        Glyph* getGlyph(const char8_t* codepoint);
        Glyph* FindGlyph(const char8_t* codepoint);

        uint32 LoadGlyph(const char8_t* codepoint);

        int InitFreeType(float size);

        char* filename;

        vector<Glyph> glyphs;
        TextureAtlas atlas;

        FT_Library library;
        FT_Face face;

        float fontSize = 0.0f;
        float ascender = 0.0f;
        float descender = 0.0f;
        float height = 0.0f;
    };
```

```cpp
int CharFromUtf8(unsigned int* out_char, const char* in_text, const char* in_text_end)
    {
        unsigned int c = (unsigned int)-1;
        const unsigned char* str = (const unsigned char*)in_text;
        if (!(*str & 0x80)) {
            c = (unsigned int)(*str++);
            *out_char = c;
            return 1;
        }
        if ((*str & 0xe0) == 0xc0) {
            *out_char = 0xFFFD;
            if (in_text_end && in_text_end - (const char*)str < 2) return 1;
            if (*str < 0xc2) return 2;
            c = (unsigned int)((*str++ & 0x1f) << 6);
            if ((*str & 0xc0) != 0x80) return 2;
            c += (*str++ & 0x3f);
            *out_char = c;
            return 2;
        }
        if ((*str & 0xf0) == 0xe0) {
            *out_char = 0xFFFD;
            if (in_text_end && in_text_end - (const char*)str < 3) return 1;
            if (*str == 0xe0 && (str[1] < 0xa0 || str[1] > 0xbf)) return 3;
            if (*str == 0xed && str[1] > 0x9f) return 3;
            c = (unsigned int)((*str++ & 0x0f) << 12);
            if ((*str & 0xc0) != 0x80) return 3;
            c += (unsigned int)((*str++ & 0x3f) << 6);
            if ((*str & 0xc0) != 0x80) return 3;
            c += (*str++ & 0x3f);
            *out_char = c;
            return 3;
        }
        if ((*str & 0xf8) == 0xf0) {
            *out_char = 0xFFFD;
            if (in_text_end && in_text_end - (const char*)str < 4) return 1;
            if (*str > 0xf4) return 4;
            if (*str == 0xf0 && (str[1] < 0x90 || str[1] > 0xbf)) return 4;
            if (*str == 0xf4 && str[1] > 0x8f) return 4; 
            c = (unsigned int)((*str++ & 0x07) << 18);
            if ((*str & 0xc0) != 0x80) return 4;
            c += (unsigned int)((*str++ & 0x3f) << 12);
            if ((*str & 0xc0) != 0x80) return 4;
            c += (unsigned int)((*str++ & 0x3f) << 6);
            if ((*str & 0xc0) != 0x80) return 4;
            c += (*str++ & 0x3f);
            if ((c & 0xFFFFF800) == 0xD800) return 4;
            *out_char = c;
            return 4;
        }
        *out_char = 0;
        return 0;
    }

    bool TextureFont::Initialize()
    {
        FT_Size_Metrics metrics;

        if (!InitFreeType(fontSize * 100.0f)) {
            return false;
        }

        metrics = face->size->metrics;
        ascender = (metrics.ascender >> 6) / 100.0f;
        descender = (metrics.descender >> 6) / 100.0f;
        height = (metrics.height >> 6) / 100.0f;

        FT_Done_Face(face);
        FT_Done_FreeType(library);

        return true;
    }

    int TextureFont::InitFreeType(float size)
    {
        FT_Matrix matrix = {
            static_cast<int>((1.0 / HIGHRES) * 0x10000L),
            static_cast<int>((0.0)           * 0x10000L),
            static_cast<int>((0.0)           * 0x10000L),
            static_cast<int>((1.0)           * 0x10000L)};
        FT_Error error;
        error = FT_Init_FreeType(&library);
        if (error) {
            EngineLogError("FREE_TYPE_ERROR: Could not Init FreeType!\n");
            FT_Done_FreeType(library);
            return 0;
        }

        error = FT_New_Face(library, filename, 0, &face);

        if (error) {
            EngineLogError("FREE_TYPE_ERROR: Could not create a new face!\n");
            FT_Done_FreeType(library);
            return 0;
        }

        error = FT_Select_Charmap(face, FT_ENCODING_UNICODE);
        if (error) {
            EngineLogError("FREE_TYPE_ERROR: Could not select charmap!\n");
            FT_Done_Face(face);
            return 0;
        }

        error = FT_Set_Char_Size(face, static_cast<ulong>(size * HIGHRES), 0, DPI * HIGHRES, DPI);
        if (error) {
            EngineLogError("FREE_TYPE_ERROR: Could not set char size!\n");
            FT_Done_Face(face);
            return 0;
        }

        FT_Set_Transform(face, &matrix, NULL);

        return 1;
    }

    void TextureFont::LoadFromFile(const std::string& filePath, float fontSize)
    {
        atlas.Create(512, 1);
        std::fill(atlas.buffer.begin(), atlas.buffer.end(), 0);
        this->fontSize = fontSize;  
        this->filename = strdup(filePath.c_str());

        Initialize();
    }

    Glyph* TextureFont::getGlyph(const char8_t* codepoint)
    {
        if (Glyph* glyph = FindGlyph(codepoint)) {
            return glyph;
        }

        if (LoadGlyph(codepoint)) {
            return FindGlyph(codepoint);
        }

        return nullptr;
    }

    Glyph* TextureFont::FindGlyph(const char8_t* codepoint)
    {
        Glyph* glyph = nullptr;
        uint32 ucodepoint;
        CharFromUtf8(&ucodepoint, (char*)codepoint, NULL);
        for (uint32 i = 0; i < glyphs.size(); ++i) {
            glyph = &glyphs[i];
            if (glyph->codepoint == ucodepoint) {
                return glyph;
            }
        }

        return nullptr;
    }

    uint32 TextureFont::LoadGlyph(const char8_t* codepoint)
    {
        FT_Error error = NULL;
        FT_Glyph ftGlyph = nullptr;
        FT_GlyphSlot slot = nullptr;
        FT_Bitmap bitmap;

        if (!InitFreeType(fontSize)) {
            return 0;
        }

        if (FindGlyph(codepoint)) {
            FT_Done_Face(face);
            FT_Done_FreeType(library);
            return 1;
        }

        unsigned int cp;
        CharFromUtf8(&cp, (char*)codepoint, NULL);
        uint32 glyphIndex = FT_Get_Char_Index(face, cp);

        int flag = 0;
        flag |= FT_LOAD_RENDER;
        flag |= FT_LOAD_FORCE_AUTOHINT;

        error = FT_Load_Glyph(face, glyphIndex, flag);
        if (error) {
            EngineLogError("FREE_TYPE_ERROR: Could not load the glyph (line {})!\n", __LINE__);
            FT_Done_Face(face);
            FT_Done_FreeType(library);
            return 0;
        }

        slot = face->glyph;
        bitmap = slot->bitmap;
        int glyphTop = slot->bitmap_top;
        int glyphLeft = slot->bitmap_left;

        uint32 srcWidth = bitmap.width / atlas.bytesPerPixel;
        uint32 srcHeight = bitmap.rows;

        uint32 tgtWidth = srcWidth;
        uint32 tgtHeight = srcHeight;

        auto buffer = std::make_unique<uchar[]>(tgtWidth * tgtHeight * atlas.bytesPerPixel);

        uchar* destPointer = buffer.get();
        uchar* srcPointer = bitmap.buffer;

        for (uint32 i = 0; i < srcHeight; ++i) {
            memcpy(destPointer, srcPointer, bitmap.width);
            destPointer += tgtWidth * atlas.bytesPerPixel;
            srcPointer += bitmap.pitch;
        }

        auto origin = atlas.PackTexture(buffer.get(), { tgtWidth, tgtHeight });

        float x = origin.x;
        float y = origin.y;

        Glyph current;
        current.codepoint = cp;
        current.width = tgtWidth;
        current.height = tgtHeight;
        current.bearing.x = glyphLeft;
        current.bearing.y = glyphTop;
        current.s0 = x / (float)atlas.textureSize.w;
        current.t0 = y / (float)atlas.textureSize.h;
        current.s1 = (x + tgtWidth) / (float)atlas.textureSize.w;
        current.t1 = (y + tgtHeight) / (float)atlas.textureSize.h;

        current.advance.x = slot->advance.x / (float)HIGHRES;
        current.advance.y = slot->advance.y / (float)HIGHRES;

        glyphs.push_back(current);

        FT_Done_Glyph(ftGlyph);
        FT_Done_Face(face);
        FT_Done_FreeType(library);

        return 1;
    }
```

to render a string (a single char in this case) I loop through string size, get a glyph, update the atlas and setup render data.

text is a simple quad with a texture on with proper uvs.
I do not think that it is necessary to explain what is inside `AddVertexData`, because it do not cause a problem.

```cpp
void DrawString(const std::u8string& string, float x, float y)
    {
        for (const auto& c : string) {
            auto glyph = textureFont.getGlyph(&c);

            auto& t = *(Texture2D*)texture.get();
            t.UpdateData(textureFont.atlas.buffer.data());

            float x0 = x + static_cast<float>(glyph->bearing.x);
            float y0 = y + (textureFont.ascender + textureFont.descender - static_cast<float>(glyph->bearing.y));
            float x1 = x0 + static_cast<float>(glyph->width);
            float y1 = y0 + static_cast<float>(glyph->height);

            float u0 = glyph->s0;
            float v0 = glyph->t0;
            float u1 = glyph->s1;
            float v1 = glyph->t1;

            //            position                uv                      color
            AddVertexData(Vector2<float>(x0, y0), Vector2<float>(u0, v0), 0xff0000ff);
            AddVertexData(Vector2<float>(x0, y1), Vector2<float>(u0, v1), 0xff0000ff);
            AddVertexData(Vector2<float>(x1, y1), Vector2<float>(u1, v1), 0xff0000ff);
            AddVertexData(Vector2<float>(x1, y0), Vector2<float>(u1, v0), 0xff0000ff);

            // indices for DrawElements() call
            // 0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 0
            AddRectElements();

            x += glyph->advance.x;
        }
    }
```

`ę` is utf-8 size == 2, so the loop runs twice, but render only 1 character and does not know the second character (because there is not any second character), so it renders the empty quad.

How to get rid of the quad that follows the character I want to render?

Comment: Using `const auto& c : string` to access **several** characters is surprising.

Comment: Note: there are two problems: **Unicode codepoints** requires 1 to 4 **bytes in UTF-8**, but for rendering **one glyph/character** you may have to 8 codepoints (or more) (modifiers), and more characters could be merged in a ligature by the fonts (so true displayed glyphs). [a cursive font uses many ligatures ("by definition of cursive")]. This is "the reference" on best practices: https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr29/tr29-35.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `DrawString` function you have the loop

```
for (const auto& c : string)
```

That loop will iterate *byte by byte* over the string. So if the string contains the two-byte `"ę"` character, then the first iteration will get the first byte, and the second iteration will get the second byte.

You can't use a range-based `for` loop here, since you need to skip bytes in the string. Either use an iterator-bases loop or an indexed-based loop.

For example

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < string.size(); /* nothing */) {
    // Here you need to get the number of bytes for the current character
    // Then you should increment the index by that amount
    i += byte_count_for_current_character;

    // ... rest of code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is in `DrawString` with `for (const auto& c : string)`

You should skip extra characters used to encode previous glyph, those matching with `0b10......`:

```
for (const auto& c : string) {
    if ((c & 0b1100'0000) == 0b1000'0000) {
        continue;
    }
// ...
}
```

or advance to the number of byte read by last glyph.

Answer (score 1):

Both calls to your actual UTF-8 decoding function `CharFromUtf8` ignore its return value, which is the number of bytes the string pointer should be advanced. Instead of the `for (const auto& c : string)` you should have a pointer which you advance by the the return value on each iteration.

Additionally, since you will be using the `CharFromUtf8` function inside that loop, you will know both the Unicode codepoint and the number of bytes to advance. Then you can refactor your `TextureFont` to take `unsigned int` (i.e. codepoints) as arguments rather than letting it do the UTF-8 decoding. This would be a better separation of concerns.

Answer (score 1):

Other answers have already identified the problem with using a range-based-for loop directly with a `std::u8string` variable.  Assuming that code point based enumeration is what you want (it probably isn't since, in general, correct glyph selection depends on surrounding code points; you probably want to iterate over extended grapheme clusters), you can use a library like [text_view](https://github.com/tahonermann/text_view) to provide range-based-for support for iteration of code points.  That loop wound then look like:

```
auto tv = make_text_view<utf8_encoding>(string);
for (const auto& cp : tv) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Interesting, I do not exactly understand `correct glyph selection depends on surrounding code points; you probably want to iterate over extended grapheme clusters`. What you mean by `surrounding codepoints` and what are `grapheme clusters`?

Comment: Extended Grapheme Clusters (EGCs) are a Unicode term used to describe a sequence of code points that are related to each other in a particular way.

Comment: Consider these two ways of encoding the letter 'á': U+00E1 (LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH ACUTE) vs U+0061 (LATIN SMALL LETTER A) + U+0301 (COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT).  The first represents the character using a single code point; the second uses two code points.  Both forms encode a single EGC and both forms should be rendered with a single glyph.  See Unicode normalization.

Comment: This is particularly relevant for emoji.  For example, family emoji are composed from sequences of code points that select family members joined together with U+200D (ZERO WIDTH JOINER).

Comment: Some helpful links:
- https://unicode.org/glossary
- https://gankra.github.io/blah/text-hates-you
- https://hsivonen.fi/string-length.